# Clock Cycles Count Variation Cortex A53 AArch64

Tags: c, arm, clock, cortex-a

I try to count cpu clock cycles for my function on ARM Cortex-A53 using following function:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
    readticks(unsigned int *result, int enabled)
    {
      struct timeval t;
      unsigned int cc;
      unsigned int val;
      if (!enabled) {
               // program the performance-counter control-register:
             asm volatile("msr pmcr_el0, %0" : : "r" (17));
             //enable all counters
             asm volatile("msr PMCNTENSET_EL0, %0" : : "r" (0x8000000f));
            //clear the overflow 
            asm volatile("msr PMOVSCLR_EL0, %0" : : "r" (0x8000000f));
             enabled = 1;
      }
      //read the coutner value
      asm volatile("mrs %0, PMCCNTR_EL0" : "=r" (cc));
      gettimeofday(&t,(struct timezone *) 0);
      result[0] = cc;
      result[1] = t.tv_usec;
      result[2] = t.tv_sec;
    }
```

and here is my user space application:

```
#include <stio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){
unsigned int init[3] = {0};
unsigned int start[3] = {0};
unsigned int end[3] = {0};
unsigned int overhead = 0;

readticks(init, 0);
readticks(start, 1);
readticks(end, 1);

overhead = end[0] - start[0];
readticks(init, 0);
readticks(start, 1);
foo(); //This is my function 
readticks(end, 1);

end[0] = end[0] - start[0] - overhead;
printf("clock cycles= %d\n", end[0]);
return 0;

}
```

When I run my code for several times, I have got different clock cycles with relatively high variation (almost 5000). My code should be run around 4000 clock cycles, but I have got 4500 - 9500 clock cycles. Is there any way around that gives me more accurate clock cycles count?

Comment: Unless you're running this on the bare metal with no OS or anything else then things like interrupts will use up cycles. Even on bare metal subtle differences in your program or the environment could lead to different cache behaviour.

Comment: The compiler might intermix your assembler code with other code! Use a **single** `asm` statement for code which belongs together! And `enabled = 1;` is useless, as the variable is not used anymore. How do you ensure your process is not preempted?

Comment: You should run code you wish to time for thousands or even millions of cycles and take an average. In some cases, the timing measurement may have poor granularity.

Comment: If you use a silly PMUSERENR_EL0 hack to access the PMUs from userspace under Linux, you will at best measure the execution of "some stuff" - including, but by no means limited to, your code - and at worst measure absolute nonsense when you read a different cycle counter to the one you started with. The code to manage the PMUs _properly_ is already right there in the kernel: seriously, if you want to actually profile something, use perf.

Comment: @Notlikethat I haven't write the readticks code by myself. It seems this method is a common method for getting approximate clock cycles of a C function. However, I've already mentioned in my question that apparently this method is not accurate enough and I am seeking for another method. So, it's greatly appreciated if you let me know what other options I have beside bare metal !

Comment: per the man page, `gettimeofday()` is obsolete and the use of `clock_gettime()` is recommended.  The `clock_gettime()` with the `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID` gets a timer of how long the specific process (the item your interested in) has been running/  The `clock_getres()` get the resolution of the requested clock.  Using the resolution, and the value from the call to clock_gettime() you can very closely calculate the number CPU cycles that the current time span has taken.

Comment: the posted code shows arrays with 3 elements, but other than setting the second and third element, those elements are never used.  Suggest modifying the code to only use the first element. (this could be done by changing the declarations to not be arrays and modifying the code accordingly.

Comment: @user3629249 Could you provide some code using `clock_gettime()` with the `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID` as an answer to this question? I'm not sure if I understood your method correctly.

Comment: you could read `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34758443/how-a-process-running-in-linux-can-determine-for-how-long-it-has-been-suspended/34770450#34770450` for some details about the timing

Answer (score 0):

Use the following macro

```
#define mfcp(rn)    ({u32 rval = 0U; \
             __asm__ __volatile__(\
               "mrc " rn "\n"\
               : "=r" (rval)\
             );\
             rval;\
             })
```

and call mfcp with the counter register:

```
uint64_t t1,t2;
t1 = mfcp(CNTPCT_EL0);
// your code
t2 = mfcp(CNTPCT_EL0);
```